# bubble chart with the bubble size equal to group size in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Would like a scatter plot (or heatmap) with the bubble size (or color) to show the size of each group in pandas.

For example, data in pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 2)), columns=['first_col', 'second_col'])
df.groupby(['first_col', 'second_col']).size()
```

In the scatter plot (or heatmap), x axis is the `first_col`, and y axis is the `second_col`, and the bubble size equal to the result from `.size()`.

It would be better if the answer can handle continuous number more than discrete number. In that case, the plotter may need set the *bin size*.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] yet; show your plotting code and explain how the results aren't what you want.

Comment: @cphlewis , the code snippet is just an example of the data I want to plot, not the codes directly used to plot the figure.

Comment: Yup, you need to try some plotting code to be Complete.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, figured it out myself.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 2)), columns=['first_col', 'second_col'])
index = df.groupby(['first_col', 'second_col']).size().index
x = index.map(lambda t: t[0])
y = index.map(lambda t: t[1])
areas = df.groupby(['first_col', 'second_col']).size()
plt.scatter(x, y, s=areas * 3, alpha=0.5)
```

[image: The plot]

Don't know how to extract x coordinate and y coordinate in a more numpy-way.

Answer (score 0):

You can further simplify the code as follows:

```py
    first_col, second_col = "first_col", "second_col"
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 2)), columns=[first_col, second_col]
    )
    df_plot = df.groupby([first_col, second_col]).size()
    plt.scatter(
        df_plot.index.get_level_values(first_col),
        df_plot.index.get_level_values(second_col),
        s=df_plot * 3,
        alpha=0.5,
    )
```

Please note that the above code will work only if you have integer values in both columns. If that is not the case, you first need to use the `pd.cut()` function to bin your data and then plot the data using the following script. Please remember to change the `np.arange()` argument to match your data.

```py
    first_col, second_col = "first_col", "second_col"
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 2), columns=[first_col, second_col])
    df["x_binned"] = pd.cut(
        df[first_col],
        np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1),
    )
    df["y_binned"] = pd.cut(df[second_col], np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
    df_plot = df.groupby(["x_binned", "y_binned"]).size()
    plt.scatter(
        pd.IntervalIndex(df_plot.index.get_level_values("x_binned")).mid,
        pd.IntervalIndex(df_plot.index.get_level_values("y_binned")).mid,
        s=df_plot * 3,
        alpha=0.5,
    )
```